# JQuery - parseHTML from an array in a loop

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have an array of strings, which I loop through and display the string and their respective div, But the strings have HTML, and I would like them to be actual HTML and not a string of text like they are currently being displayed.

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="line__0"></div>
<div class="line__1"></div>
<div class="line__2"></div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var textLines = [
  "Line <strong>0</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>1</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>1</strong>."
];

function text(i) {
  for (i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
    $('.line__' + i).html(textLines[i]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Provide MCVE. Your code would already set it as HTML content, not string. That's said, passing `i` to `text()` method doesn't make sense here because anyway you are redefining `i` in loop declaration, even it shoudl be: `for (var i = 0;...)`. That's said, you don't need any `for` loop here: https://jsfiddle.net/nqj30mz0/1

Comment: why you have made text() function. just put loop outside function or call that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the function text, it can be done without it just by putting your code directely inside the ready function :

```js
var textLines = [
  "Line <strong>0</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>1</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>2</strong>."
];

for (i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
  $('.line__' + i).html(textLines[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line__0"></div>
<div class="line__1"></div>
<div class="line__2"></div>
```

Or you can use the function without passing any parameter, just `text()` :

```js
var textLines = [
  "Line <strong>0</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>1</strong>.",
  "Line <strong>2</strong>."
];

function text() {
   for (i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
       $('.line__' + i).html(textLines[i]);
   }
}

text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line__0"></div>
<div class="line__1"></div>
<div class="line__2"></div>
```

Hope this helps.